# Magento1 : How to add content near image in product view page using XML?

Tags: magento2, xml, layout-update

I want to add content after the image, but i cant, i tried:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.media.preview2" template="product/view/preview_image.phtml" before="product.info.media" />...
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.media.preview2" template="product/view/preview_image.phtml" before="product.media" />...
```

and i tried it in some different contents:

```
<referenceContainer name="main">
<referenceContainer name="content">
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
```

But nothing works, and i know the xml works.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the referenceContainer, it was:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
```